# How to change network config through command line?

Tags: command-line-interface, windows-command-prompt, windows-8.1

The system is **Windows 8.1** Professional.

I want to change through `command line` my network config to this one :

[image]

How to do that ?

Answer (score 3):

For IP:

```
netsh interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection" static 192.168.1.68 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.168
```

For Primary DNS:

```
netsh interface ip set dns name="Local Area Connection" static 196.192.32.5
```

For Seondary DNS:

```
netsh interface ip add dns name="Local Area Connection" 41.188.9.130 index=2
```

"Local Area Connection" = your Ethernet

Good Luck

Comment: I got error : `The syntax of the file name, directory or volume incorrect`.

Comment: @pheromix:  I suspect it's because you didn't adapt the answer to your connection's name which is probably "Connexion au réseau local".

Comment: after changing the name I got these errors : `Impossible de configurer le service DHCP. L'interface est peut-être déconnectée.

Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.`